# is it possible (or mandatory) to use apostrophe after the word minutes in this case?

Tags: apostrophe

I am doing my business course assessent and the teacher gave us a case study about a coffee shop. The coffee has a policy of serving within 2 minutes.
Of course, in my answer, I can write "waiting time of 2 minutes" (or any other variation).

However, a question came accross my mind.
Is it possible to use apostrophe after the words minutes, seconds, etc., as we do with years?
Following the same structure of "2 years' experience", can I say the café has a '2 minutes' waiting time policy". Is this sentence correct?

What about "2-minute waiting time policy"? or "2-minutes' waiting time policy".

I am quite confused about which sentence would fit better.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the apostrophe, if we want to form a possessive noun, as in your example one.  Otherwise, no apostrophes are used.

> **2 minutes'** waiting time policy

> **2-minute** waiting time policy

The above two examples are fine.
**2 minutes'** is a plural possessive noun; and **2-minute**, an attributive noun.  Attributive nouns are more commonly singular.

The example below is less common.

> **2-minutes'** waiting time policy

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=2-minutes%27%2C2-minute%27&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)